# how can I pass the props (id in particular) down to another component?

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation, react-props

This is my first attempt at creating a react native project (with redux as well) and I have a question relating to passing down info. I have an API that looks like this :

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Module 1",
"topics": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Iterators and Helpers",
"course_id": 1
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Object Oriented Ruby",
"course_id": 1
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "One to Many Relationships",
"course_id": 1
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Many to Many Relationships",
"course_id": 1
},
{
"id": 5,
"name": "Active Record Basics",
"course_id": 1
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Module 2",
"topics": [
{
"id": 9,
"name": "Introduction to Sinatra",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 10,
"name": "Sinatra CRUD",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 11,
"name": "Sinatra Associations",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 12,
"name": "Introduction to Rails",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 13,
"name": "Rails Forms + CRUD",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 14,
"name": "Rails Associations + CRUD",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 15,
"name": "Rails Sessions and Cookies",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 16,
"name": "Rails Authentication and Authorization",
"course_id": 2
},
{
"id": 17,
"name": "Module 2 Project Guidelines",
"course_id": 2
}
]
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Module 3",
"topics": [
{
"id": 18,
"name": "Introduction to JavaScript",
"course_id": 3
},
{
"id": 19,
"name": "Introduction to Document Object Model",
"course_id": 3
},
{
"id": 20,
"name": "JavaScript Events",
"course_id": 3
},
{
"id": 21,
"name": "JavaScript Asynchronous Functionality + Fetch & CRUD",
"course_id": 3
```

Each 'module' has many topics. I want the Modules to appear on one screen and the topics for each course to appear once a button is clicked. I have this so far:

```
render(){
      console.log(this.props.courseNames)
       return(
        <FlatList style={styles.flatlist} keyExtractor={(item)=> item.id} data={this.props.courseNames} ItemSeparatorComponent = { this.FlatListItemSeparator } 
        renderItem={({item}) => { 
         return <TouchableOpacity><Button title={item.name} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Topics')} style={styles.listitem}/></TouchableOpacity>
        }}
        ListHeaderComponent = {this.header}/>
       )
     }
  }
```

This is just a snippet but I'm wondering how I can pass down the information specific to that class so that I can retrieve all the topics that it contains and display them on the next screen. Any pointers would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to pass 'parameters' to navigation routes, which, yes, do render components that can receive props from the navigation route parameter.

In your case,

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Topics')
```

should be changed to;

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Topics', {id:item.id})
```

Once you navigate to your Topics route, that component will be able to read the 'id' value from;

```
props.route.params.id
```

Route parameters will be any object passed after the route name in `this.props.navigation.navigate` method.